# I am trying to use pytorch's implementation of XLNet and got 'Trying to create tensor with negative dimension -1: [-1, 768]' when loading XLNet

Tags: pytorch, tensor, transformer-model

I started working on this about two months ago on Google Colab for a midterm project and everything worked perfectly. Now I am modifying it for a final project and keep getting the error 'RuntimeError: Trying to create tensor with negative dimension -1: [-1, 768]'. It looks like pytorch recently pushed a new version 1.5, so I downgraded to version 1.4 and still got the same error. Same with 1.3, and I know I wasn't using anything lower since that came out last year. I checked it with my midterm code and still got the same error, so I don't know what's going on. Here is the chunk of code related to downloading and using the model.

```
    train_inputs, validation_inputs, train_labels, validation_labels = train_test_split(inputIds, 
                                                                                        labels, 
                                                                                        random_state=2020, 
                                                                                        test_size=0.2)
    train_masks, validation_masks, _, _ = train_test_split(attention_masks, inputIds, random_state=2020, 
                                                           test_size=0.2)
    # Turn data into torch tensors
    train_inputs = torch.tensor(train_inputs)
    validation_inputs = torch.tensor(validation_inputs)
    train_labels = torch.tensor(train_labels)
    validation_labels = torch.tensor(validation_labels)
    train_masks = torch.tensor(train_masks)
    validation_masks = torch.tensor(validation_masks)

    # Create Iterators of the datasets
    train_data = TensorDataset(train_inputs, train_masks, train_labels)
    train_sampler = RandomSampler(train_data)
    train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_data, sampler=train_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)
    validation_data = TensorDataset(validation_inputs, validation_masks, validation_labels)
    validation_sampler = SequentialSampler(validation_data)
    validation_dataloader = DataLoader(validation_data, sampler=validation_sampler, batch_size=batch_size)

    model = XLNetForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased', num_labels=2)
    # Loads model into GPU memory
    model.cuda()

    param_optimizer = list(model.named_parameters())
    no_decay = ['bias','gamma','beta']
    optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
        {'params':[p for n, p in param_optimizer if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
         'weight_decay_rate':0.01},
        {'params':[p for n, p in param_optimizer if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
         'weight_decay_rate':0.0}
    ]
    optimizer = AdamW(optimizer_grouped_parameters, lr=2e-5)
```

The error happens on the line `model = XLNetForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased', num_labels=2)`. The packages I am using:

```
from pandas import to_datetime
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader, RandomSampler, SequentialSampler
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# MUST INSTALL PYTORCH-TRANSFORMERS
from pytorch_transformers import XLNetTokenizer, XLNetForSequenceClassification, AdamW
from tqdm import trange
from numpy import argmax, sum 
import nltk
nltk.download('punkt')
```

Thank you to anyone who tries to help.

Comment: couldn't reproduce your error in google colab https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1A8edGYyFuE7d1Z-ZJusz5zU_7yCevF2L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try transformers instead of pytorch_transformers.

`! pip install transformers` (Google Colab)

In terminal,

`pip install transformers`

```
import torch

from transformers import XLNetForSequenceClassification

model = XLNetForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained('xlnet-base-cased', num_labels=2)

model.cuda()

param_optimizer = list(model.named_parameters())
no_decay = ['bias','gamma','beta']
optimizer_grouped_parameters = [
    {'params':[p for n, p in param_optimizer if not any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
      'weight_decay_rate':0.01},
    {'params':[p for n, p in param_optimizer if any(nd in n for nd in no_decay)],
      'weight_decay_rate':0.0}
]
```

Here's the code without any error in google colab: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1A8edGYyFuE7d1Z-ZJusz5zU_7yCevF2L

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I forgot to change pytorch_transformers to transformers when I checked this earlier today.